# Python equivalent of PyErr_Print()

Tags: python, c, cpython, sys, traceback

What is the Python API equivalent of `PyErr_Print()`, from the C interface?

I'm assuming a call in either the `sys`, or `traceback` modules, but can't find any functions therein that make calls to `PyErr_Print()`.

### Addendum

I'm after the Python call to get the same functionality as `PyErr_PrintEx()`, described as:

```
Print a standard traceback to sys.stderr and clear the error indicator.
```

That is I want to make the **Python** call that has this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no Python function that's exactly equivalent to `PyErr_PrintEx` (the real name of `PyErr_Print`;-), including for example setting `sys.last_traceback` and friends (which are only supposed to be set to help a post-mortem debugging from the interactive interpreter for exceptions which have **not** been caught).  What exact combination of functionality are you looking for?

Comment: I just noticed the slight discrepancy, I'm after the printing and clearing bit.

Comment: Only way to "clear [[the error]] bit" in Python code is to catch the exception in an `except` clause of a `try/except` statement (sometimes this can be implicit, in the `__exit__` method of the context manager in a `with` statement).

Comment: ok, what about the printing part, what is the closest call? `print_exc`?

Comment: Yep, `traceback.print_exc` is the closest analog.